# Doxygen behavior for function defined with trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++11, doxygen, trailing-return-type, return-type-deduction

The [changelog](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/changelog.html) of doxygen release 1.8.2 says that support has been added to C++11 trailing return types. However, parsing my codes with doxygen version 1.8.4 results in the return types being `auto` and not the trailing return type.

Is there any option that need to be set to get this working properly?

**Edit:**

In the figure below it can be seen that the return types are `auto`, which, I believe, is not the correct behaviour.

[image]

Comment: No, please add an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @doxygen I am pretty sure the desired doxygen output here would be that the trailing return type is shown as a normal return type would. So the declaration `int main();` and `auto main() -> int;` would both result in the exact same HTML documentation (that looks like the documentation for `int main()` has looked the whole time).

Comment: @jPlatte Then why would one write the code using the trailing return type in the first place?

Comment: In some cases you have to use trailing return types, otherwise they wouldn't exist. And some people like to use them because then all the function names are on the same text column in a text editor. They can also be shorter in some cases when the return type is a type dependent on the struct / class the function is a member of.

Comment: Note that C++14 supports function return type deduction, and I wonder if Doxygen will one day be able to deduce the type as well. Or Doxygen starts considering these new C++ features, or it will eventually become only usable for old C++ projects.

Comment: Well I guess Doxygen would appreciate if you contributed code to their project :)

Comment: Sure, like if it was that simple to contribute to code to all projects one relies on! Anyway, I figured out how to solve this using JavaScript and jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

This is an open Doxygen issue on GitHub:

[C++11 new function declaration syntax is not recognized correctly (Origin: bugzilla #730794)](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/5492)

but the author of Doxygen wants a clarification on exactly what you expect Doxygen to do.

Comment: @Allan : Please follow the link and consider either accepting this answer or commenting.